# download webm file from client with nodejs

Tags: node.js, client, blob, server, webm

I have created a webm file in the client with whammy.js and the media html tag.
I have the url for the webm file created on the client. It looks like this:

```
blob:http%3A//localhost%3A3000/543e2866-f145-4ea8-96f8-c66eb78cbda2
```

I want to download the file to my server. Im using the download module on my nodejs server, but im getting an error:

```
Error: Specify a valid URL
```

Why is that? How can i download the file to the server?

Thank you!

Update: below is the handler for download

```
module.exports = function(io) {
    var Download    = require('download'),
        progress    = require('download-status'),
        dir         = './downloads/';

    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        console.log('We have Lift-off!');
        socket.on('video url', function (data) {
            console.log(data.video_url);
            var url = data.video_url.slice(5);
            console.log(url);
            var download = new Download({ strip: 1, mode: '755' })
                .get(url)
                .dest(dir)
                .use(progress());

            download.run(function (err, files, stream) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }
                console.log('File downloaded successfully!');
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Paste your code if you have troubles implementing slice

Comment: If the file was created in the client, shouldn't it be **uploaded** to the server not downloaded?

Comment: Thought about uploading it, but because the file is so small (only 3 sec long) i thought it might be easier to download the url. Anyway, any method that will get the file on my server will be alright with me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I end up uploading the file with simple fs.

Client:

```
var files = {
    video: {
        name: fileName + '.webm',
        type: 'video/webm',
        dataURL: output
    }
}
socket.emit('video', files);
```

Whammy creates the dataURL so we can simply emit it as JSON to server with socket.io.

Server:

```
module.exports = function(io) {
    var fs          = require('fs'),
        path        = require('path'),
        upload_dir  = './uploads',
        output_dir  = './outputs';

    function _upload(file_content, file_name) {
        var fileRootName = file_name.split('.').shift(),
        fileExtension = file_name.split('.').pop(),
        filePathBase = upload_dir + '/',
        fileRootNameWithBase = filePathBase + fileRootName,
        filePath = fileRootNameWithBase + '.' + fileExtension,
        fileID = 2;

        while (fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
            filePath = fileRootNameWithBase + '(' + fileID + ').' + fileExtension;
            fileID += 1;
        }

        fs.writeFileSync(filePath, file_content);
    }

    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

        console.log('We have Lift-off!');
        socket.on('video url', function (data) {
            console.log(data.video_url);
        });

        socket.on('video', function (data) {
            console.log('writing to disk');
            console.log(data.video.dataURL);
            console.log(data.video.name);
            _upload(data.video.dataURL, data.video.name);
        });
    });
}
```

With fs we take care of saving the file on the server-side.

works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the first 5 characters from the URL.

You can use `url.slice(5);`